# How can I connect Jprofiler with weblogic managed servers?

Tags: weblogic, jprofiler

I am trying to connect Jprofiler7 to remote weblogic10.3 managed servers. I am able to connect and see admin console threads and memory usage in JProfiler but not for application deployed on managed server.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with WebLogic 12C on windows with JProfiler9 and solved it as follows:

1. Allow JProfiler to create startWebLogic_jprofiler.cmd by profiling WebLogic 12C, but don't attach the profiler at this point.
2. Edit startManagedWebLogic.cmd and call startWebLogic_jprofiler.cmd rather than startWebLogic.cmd
3. At a command prompt execute startWebLogic.cmd
4. At a command prompt execute startManagedWebLogic.cmd
5. In JProfiler, click "Start Center" icon. Click "New Server Integration". Select "Generic application server" and then "Wait for a connection from the JProfiler GUI". When the profiler starts it collects data from the managed weblogic server.

Answer (score 1):

You're profiling the wrong server in that case. The VM parameter for JProfiler (-agentpath:...) has to be added to the JVM on which your application is executed.