# How to run Jprofile with weblogic 10.x managed server?

Tags: java, weblogic, jprofiler

**Question:**

How to make Jprofile 9.1 collect data from specific manged server and not from admin server?

**Details:**

By going with Jprofile wizard (Profile application server) I am able to attached Jprofile to the running Admin server but I am unable to find any option that allow me to monitor specific manged server.

In this question [How can I connect Jprofiler with weblogic managed servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017004/how-can-i-connect-jprofiler-with-weblogic-managed-servers)

one of the answer says the following:

> You're profiling the wrong server in that case. The VM parameter for JProfiler (-agentpath:...) has to be added to the JVM on which your application is executed.

The answer trying to point to some parameter changes to be done but it is not clear how to do it.

Comment: You can configure VM parameters for the managed server. The `-agentpath` parameter given by the remote integration wizard has to be added to those parameters. Then you can connect with a remote profiling session.

Comment: @IngoKegel I am running Jprofile on the same server where weblogic is running. So I need to add the parameter in manged server startup like `-agentpath:[path goes here]\jprofilerti.dll=port=8849` then start the session in Jprofile with the file `startWebLogic_jprofiler.cmd` ? I did that but Admin server console is only showing, still manged server resources is not captured ?

Comment: Then you are still profiling the admin server. The answer by @Yogesh_D is good. It does not matter whether you run the managed server locally or remotely.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a question that talks about setting JVM parameters for weblogic servers.

[custom arguments to set in weblogic JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158199/custom-arguments-to-set-in-weblogic-jvm)

> 1. In the Domain Structure pane, expand the Servers node.
> 2. Click the name of the server that you want to configure.
> 3. In the right pane, click Server Start. Select Lock & Edit.
> 4. In the Arguments text box, provide the JVM options. After inserting your options, click Save.
> 5. Then click Activate Changes.
> 6. Restart the server so that the new
>      settings are used.

You should be able to set the relevant agentLib argument use the above described procedure.

Note, you need to copy the agent libraries onto the host that has the managed server.

Comment: Kindly check my comment in the question

Comment: Run Jprofiler anywhere you want to so long as you have n/w connectivity with the Managed server. Have the managed servers's JVM args modified to add the agentlib jvm argument as mentioned in the Jprofiler docs, and ensure that the files needed by Jprofiler are present on this managed server. You should be able to connect.